# Visual studio how to get wpf and silverlight side by side

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, silverlight

I have two projects in my solution one a silverlight library and the other a wpf control library, ive added the sources as a link from my silverlight library to my wpf library and after a bit of refatoring hit a road block, my wpf library project does not want to build the generated files needed for the code behind to recocnize the named elements from the xaml sources (which where added as links), does anyone know how to prompt visual studio 2008 to actually perform the gen operation on my linked sources?

Comment: It should 'just work' - did you link the files properly (compare the underlying contents of the .csproj between WPF and Silverlight to be sure)?

Comment: I sure did, I even checked the generated files and it seems that wpf doesnt do name resolution in InitalizeComponent like silverlight or perhaps only in this case,however I keep getting a compiler warning that this variable doesnt exist in this context? which is a name to an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stab in the dark - but have you renamed a namespace or class name? 
Make sure all the code/xaml namespace/class names are the same in wpf and silverlight versions.

Comment: Wow, spot on my wpf app did infact have a different namespace